# Keyboard shortcut to Save As in MS Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, keyboard-shortcuts, save-as

I am creating PDF from word documents. I need to take more steps to save MS Word 2010 Document into PDF.

**Keyboard shortcut to Save As in MS Word 2010?**

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+S` should work.

Comment: @SagarBalyan In other program/product like Photoshop, we can use **Ctrl+Shift+S** for Save As. That's why each & every time I implicitly try to use that command, but it's not working in MS Word 2010.

Comment: `Alt+F+A` will do the job.

Comment: @SagarBalyan **Alt+F+A** also works for that purpose, but another user suggest me **F12** which was more better. Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1):

If you had tried Google or Bing you would have found the [full list of keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-on-Windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2?ctt=1&CorrelationId=7e8c0a44-3a82-4299-82aa-10dd38e1f4c6&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010370109#OfficeVersion=2010,_2007), which would have informed you that whereas `Ctrl+Shift+S` displays a dialog to apply styles `F12` shows the SaveAs dialog.